# Get element from array

Tags: pgfplotstable, arrays

considering the generic table `\mytable`, to get an element from there I am using `\pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{[index]\column}\of\mytable`.

but if I don't have a table but an array?

the case is this: `\def\array{alba, prova, 13, CO\ped{2}}`

I would like to create `\singleElement` that takes the third element of the array.

How can I do?

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: For a one dimensional array (presumably one element per line) one could do the whole thing using plain tex commands line \newread, \openin, \read, \closein, and \csname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way mey be to define it this way:

```
\def\singleElement#1,#2,#3,#4\close{#3}
```

And then invoke it using:

```
\expandafter\singleElement\array,,,\close
```

This way `\singleElement` has four arguments, separated by commas, where `#4` is ended by `\close` (well you can choose any `\`-sequence you prefer for that, just replace `\close` with, say, `\foo` everywhere in the above). The way I called it is: your `\array` contains a list of comma-separated elements, so I make it expand (`\expandafter` makes TeX read `\array` before `\singleElement`, so `\array` is replaced with the comma-separated list *before* `\singleElement` tries to do its job), then `\singleElement` looks for its arguments, and the commas make sure it finds them, for if `\array` doesn't have enough elements you would get an error as the commas for `\singleElement`'s arguments would not be found, whereas this way if `\array` has less than 4 elements (i.e. less than 3 commas) it finds all necessary commas afterwards and the `\close` to finish argument 4.

Naturally this forces `\array` to separate its elements by commas, but then you can substitute commas with whatever token you want. If you want dots as separators, you can do:

```
\def\singleElement#1.#2.#3.#4\close{#3}
```

and call it by:

```
\expandafter\singleElement\array...\close
```

And you can use numbers, punctuation signs, even letter sequences:

```
\def\singleElement#1abc#2abc#3abc#4\close{#3}
\expandafter\singleElement\array abc abc abc\close
```

would have `abc` as the element separator, but that is definitely not advisable :).

Of course, this is a solution that doesn't use `pgfplots`, so maybe it is not what you expected, but it will work even without loading `pgfplots`. In fact, it doesn't even require `LaTeX`: Plain `TeX` is enough for it.

Comment: What if the array has more than nine arguments? ;-)

Comment: Well he asked for the third :). Anyway one can always extract a super-long number 9 and call the macro again on that one. In other words, a little recursion.